# How to intercept GraphQL Hotchocolate Banana Cake Pop Query in Resolver

Tags: asp.net, graphql, hotchocolate

Is there a way to intercept a query that is passed from the (BananaCakePop/Hotchocolate) playground and read the contents of it?

Currently I am trying to use IHttpContextAccessor httpContext in my resolver which is injected after configuring my services in Startup.cs ->`services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`;

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Account>> MyResolver(
        [Service] IHttpContextAccessor httpContext,
        [Service] IConfigService configService)
```

However I am not able to see my query in the request.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to read the document you can just inject `IResolverContext` and access the `Document`

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Account>> MyResolver(
        [Service] IHttpContextAccessor httpContext,
        [Service] IConfigService configService,
        IResolverContext resolverContext) 
{
   resolverContext.Document <---
}
```